# zfs pool with slow speed on SAS drive with high latency

Tags: linux, hard-drive, zfsonlinux, firmware, raid-controller

We have 3 servers in a gluster pool.
Each computer's spec is (Advance STOR-2 Gen 2 at OVH):

- AMD Ryzen 7 Pro 3700 - 8c/16t - 3.6 GHz/4.4 GHz
- 6 x 14 TB disk (WD DC HC 530, using CMR technologies) [western Digital Documentation](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/product/data-center-drives/ultrastar-dc-hc500-series/data-sheet-ultrastar-dc-hc530.pdf)
- 2 supplemental drives for the system.
- 64 Go ECC 2933 MHz

The specs below are of one machine, but should be similar if not identical to the others.

System:

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- 5.15.0-69-generic

zfs version:

- zfs-2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1
- zfs-kmod-2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1

controler:

- ```
  2b:00.0 Mass storage controller [0180]: Broadcom / LSI SAS3008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-3 [1000:0097] (rev 02)
        Subsystem: Broadcom / LSI SAS3008 PCI-Express Fusion-MPT SAS-3 [1000:1000]
        Kernel driver in use: mpt3sas
        Kernel modules: mpt3sas
  ```

I cannot tell how is configured the controller (HBA or not) but

- no hardware raid is available on this type of machine
- I have access to each drive's smart data. (so if not HBA, at least JBOD)

We had a faulty drive, and performed a replacement.
That's when we identify a problem:

```
#> zpool status; echo; date
 pool: storage
state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
       continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
 scan: resilver in progress since Tue Apr 18 20:44:53 2023
       17.4T scanned at 27.9M/s, 17.4T issued at 27.9M/s, 17.7T total
       3.31T resilvered, 98.12% done, 03:29:17 to go
config:

       NAME                                      STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
       storage                                   DEGRADED     0     0     0
         raidz2-0                                DEGRADED     0     0     0
           wwn-0x5000cca2ad235164                ONLINE       0     0     0
           wwn-0x5000cca28f4ec59c                ONLINE       0     0     0
           wwn-0x5000cca2ad29cc1c                ONLINE       0     0     0
           wwn-0x5000cca2a31743d4                ONLINE       0     0     0
           wwn-0x5000cca2a40f9b00                ONLINE       0     0     0
           replacing-5                           DEGRADED     0     0     0
             9949261471066455025                 UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x5000cca2ad2eba3c-part1
             scsi-SWDC_WUH721414AL5201_9LKLGWSG  ONLINE       0     0     0  (resilvering)

errors: No known data errors

Wed Apr 26 10:44:02 UTC 2023
```

Forgot to show you the usage of the pool :

```
zpool list
NAME      SIZE  ALLOC   FREE  CKPOINT  EXPANDSZ   FRAG    CAP  DEDUP    HEALTH  ALTROOT
storage  76.4T  18.3T  58.1T        -         -    15%    23%  1.00x    ONLINE  -

Fri Apr 28 14:32:58 UTC 2023
```

Though the gluster is running in parallel, I don't think it's causing much throughput.

Then comes the very high latency:

In `dmesg` I have seen these outputs:

```
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023] INFO: task txg_sync:1985 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]       Tainted: P           O      5.15.0-69-generic #76-Ubuntu
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023] "echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023] task:txg_sync        state:D stack:    0 pid: 1985 ppid:     2 flags:0x00004000
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023] Call Trace:
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  <TASK>
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  __schedule+0x24e/0x590
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  schedule+0x69/0x110
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  cv_wait_common+0xf8/0x130 [spl]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? wait_woken+0x70/0x70
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  __cv_wait+0x15/0x20 [spl]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  arc_read+0x1e1/0x15c0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? arc_evict_cb_check+0x20/0x20 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  dsl_scan_visitbp+0x4f5/0xcf0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  dsl_scan_visitbp+0x333/0xcf0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  dsl_scan_visitbp+0x333/0xcf0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  dsl_scan_visitbp+0x333/0xcf0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  dsl_scan_visitbp+0x333/0xcf0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  dsl_scan_visitbp+0x333/0xcf0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  dsl_scan_visitbp+0x813/0xcf0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  dsl_scan_visit_rootbp+0xe8/0x160 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  dsl_scan_visitds+0x15d/0x4b0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? __kmalloc_node+0x166/0x3a0
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? do_raw_spin_unlock+0x9/0x10 [spl]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? __raw_spin_unlock+0x9/0x10 [spl]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? __list_add+0x17/0x40 [spl]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? do_raw_spin_unlock+0x9/0x10 [spl]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? __raw_spin_unlock+0x9/0x10 [spl]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? tsd_hash_add+0x145/0x180 [spl]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? tsd_set+0x98/0xd0 [spl]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  dsl_scan_visit+0x1ae/0x2c0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  dsl_scan_sync+0x412/0x910 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  spa_sync_iterate_to_convergence+0x124/0x1f0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  spa_sync+0x2dc/0x5b0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  txg_sync_thread+0x266/0x2f0 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? txg_dispatch_callbacks+0x100/0x100 [zfs]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  thread_generic_wrapper+0x64/0x80 [spl]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? __thread_exit+0x20/0x20 [spl]
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  kthread+0x12a/0x150
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ? set_kthread_struct+0x50/0x50
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  ret_from_fork+0x22/0x30
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023]  </TASK>
```

Not very frequent, but still too many: (uptime: 11:10:30 up 7 days, 15:27)

```
[Thu Apr 20 07:47:49 2023] INFO: task txg_sync:1985 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Thu Apr 20 09:08:22 2023] INFO: task txg_sync:1985 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Thu Apr 20 09:38:35 2023] INFO: task txg_sync:1985 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Thu Apr 20 10:16:51 2023] INFO: task txg_sync:1985 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Thu Apr 20 10:26:55 2023] INFO: task txg_sync:1985 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Fri Apr 21 07:57:48 2023] INFO: task txg_sync:1985 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Fri Apr 21 08:58:13 2023] INFO: task txg_sync:1985 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Fri Apr 21 09:32:27 2023] INFO: task txg_sync:1985 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Fri Apr 21 10:00:39 2023] INFO: task txg_sync:1985 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
[Tue Apr 25 10:30:31 2023] INFO: task txg_sync:1985 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
```

Disks age is rather young, nothing noticeable here :

```
smart_WUH721414AL5201_81G8L1SV.log : power on : 259 days, 21:21:00
smart_WUH721414AL5201_9LHD9Z7G.log : power on : 197 days, 19:08:00
smart_WUH721414AL5201_9LKLGWSG.log : power on : 7 days, 17:25:00
smart_WUH721414AL5201_QBGDTMXT.log : power on : 255 days, 21:44:00
smart_WUH721414AL5201_Y6GME43C.log : power on : 346 days, 22:59:00
smart_WUH721414AL5201_Y6GRZLKC.log : power on : 197 days, 12:56:00
```

iostat is not alarming (though an average output, iowait doesn't reach higher than 10, 15% at most) :

```
avg-cpu:  %user   %nice %system %iowait  %steal   %idle
           0.13    0.00    1.49    6.65    0.00   91.73

Device            r/s     rkB/s   rrqm/s  %rrqm r_await rareq-sz     w/s     wkB/s   wrqm/s  %wrqm w_await wareq-sz     d/s     dkB/s   drqm/s  %drqm d_await dareq-sz     f/s f_await  aqu-sz  %util
sda            369.80   6115.05     0.04   0.01    5.25    16.54   10.81    328.36     0.01   0.06    0.77    30.38    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.19    7.87    1.95  80.10
sdb            412.40   6215.40     0.02   0.01    5.43    15.07   10.69    328.41     0.01   0.06    0.78    30.72    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.19   10.06    2.25  88.23
sdc            395.09   6004.60     0.02   0.00    5.49    15.20   10.72    328.56     0.01   0.07    0.78    30.66    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.19    8.66    2.18  85.42
sdd            412.57   6229.91     0.02   0.01    5.57    15.10   10.34    328.57     0.01   0.05    0.84    31.77    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.19   14.77    2.31  90.34
sde            374.34   6150.81     0.03   0.01    5.33    16.43   10.74    328.43     0.01   0.06    0.78    30.58    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.19    8.47    2.01  81.84
sdf             25.72    113.11     0.00   0.00    2.82     4.40  219.12   5713.02     0.09   0.04    1.25    26.07    0.00      0.00     0.00   0.00    0.00     0.00    0.18   49.05    0.36  27.09
```

but zpool latency is (all disks have more than 1 second latency):

```
zpool iostat -w

storage      total_wait     disk_wait    syncq_wait    asyncq_wait
latency      read  write   read  write   read  write   read  write  scrub   trim
----------  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----  -----
1ns             0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
[...] # all zeros
127ns           0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
255ns           0      0      0      0  1.17K      0     12  2.43K  1.61M      0
511ns           0      0      0      0   616K   484K  19.4K  1.39M   121M      0
1us             0      0      0      0  4.65M   895K   205K  10.4M   126M      0
2us             0      0      0      0  11.9M  49.4K   209K  2.74M  9.56M      0
4us             0      0      0      0  7.17M  4.99K  42.5K   168K  2.76M      0
8us             0      0      0      0  53.0K  1.37K    657   163K  3.96M      0
16us           72      0    315      0  11.7K    374    533   172K  2.84M      0
32us        61.3M      4  65.2M     36    768      8    201   269K  4.36M      0
65us        60.8M     96  60.6M    566    236      0    343   426K  6.04M      0
131us       79.4M    271  81.6M    879     80      0    734   824K  7.92M      0
262us       35.0M   443K   175M   464K    116      0  5.64K  2.11M  11.2M      0
524us       36.0M  8.21M   186M  50.5M     44      0  5.09K  5.27M  5.60M      0
1ms         17.5M  9.73M  58.8M  59.5M     89      0  2.63K  5.75M  3.15M      0
2ms         5.30M  13.9M  39.0M  41.3M    114      0  2.31K  9.08M  3.73M      0
4ms         6.29M  15.3M  97.1M  15.8M    176      0  3.48K  11.8M  6.05M      0
8ms         13.5M  12.3M   201M  2.59M    277      0  6.76K  9.97M  9.68M      0
16ms        26.7M  8.84M   198M   779K    334      0  8.13K  8.10M  14.9M      0
33ms        36.1M  9.82M  75.3M   275K    218      0  6.30K  9.17M  23.4M      0
67ms        41.8M  10.8M  12.5M  48.9K    215      0  2.79K  10.5M  37.1M      0
134ms       59.3M  9.52M  1.92M  9.46K    213      0    680  9.33M  57.2M      0
268ms       88.0M  7.43M   543K    893    272      0    121  7.35M  86.7M      0
536ms        132M  7.58M   389K    140    521      0     19  7.55M   131M      0
1s           190M  9.42M  21.4K     59    795      0      8  9.41M   189M      0
2s           205M  12.8M  2.09K     16  1.26K      0      0  12.8M   204M      0
4s           110M  17.9M    565      8  1.36K      0      0  17.9M   109M      0
8s          33.2M  15.0M      0      0    955      0      0  15.0M  33.0M      0
17s         11.3M  2.38M      0      0    269      0      0  2.38M  11.3M      0
34s         3.40M  18.4K      0      0     81      0      0  18.4K  3.40M      0
68s          392K      0      0      0     30      0      0      0   391K      0
137s        31.4K      0      0      0     13      0      0      0  31.4K      0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

1 second latency:

```
zpool iostat -vw | awk '/^1s/'

1s                                         191M  9.42M  21.5K     59    795      0      8  9.41M   190M      0
1s                                         191M  9.42M  21.5K     59    795      0      8  9.41M   190M      0
1s                                        31.6M      0  3.72K      0    117      0      0      0  31.4M      0
1s                                        41.1M      0  4.06K      0    198      0      0      0  41.0M      0
1s                                        41.8M      0  4.31K      0    171      0      0      0  41.7M      0
1s                                        40.3M     15  4.14K      0    204      0      0     15  40.2M      0
1s                                        35.8M      2  3.98K      0    105      0      0      1  35.6M      0
1s                                        1.91K  9.42M  1.29K     59      0      0      8  9.41M    554      0
1s                                            0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
1s                                        1.91K  9.42M  1.29K     59      0      0      8  9.41M    554      0
```

I apologize for all this information. I tried to be concise.

Just to be clear, I am trying to find the reason behind this crawling speed. But everything I have been looking at, seems correct.

- smartctl report is not alarming (as exchange with OVH)

  - I did find it alarming that the ECC came into play, but I doubt 18 drives are bad:

```
smart_WUH721414AL5201_81G8L1SV.log - total errors corrected -> 193
smart_WUH721414AL5201_9LHD9Z7G.log - total errors corrected -> 4
smart_WUH721414AL5201_QBGDTMXT.log - total errors corrected -> 6
smart_WUH721414AL5201_Y6GME43C.log - total errors corrected -> 13
```

Anyway, I am at a loss here. If you have any idea where to look for, or if you require any more information, please, just ask!

Thank you for your time.

Edit: added output of `zpool list`

- The rebuild finally finished : `Fri Apr 28 03:33:32 2023`

Comment: Looks like you have ~ 1 and 1/2 hours to go before resilver is done.

Comment: I wish, but it's magically still going : `98.65% done, 02:35:35 to go`

Comment: Hahaha, even this morning, it's still going on : 99.89% done, 00:13:26 to go :'-(

Comment: That is brutally slow. Other disk activity can slow it down but that is still very slow.

Comment: You tell me ^^ the thing is, I have absolutely no ideas of what could be the cause. BTW I forgot to specify, the pool is composed of 6x14TB drives (in raidz1), must be 30 TB used, at most.